Is there any possible way to make each party obtain the output in a MPC protocol?
I konw a fact that it is impossible to achieve complete fairness in 2-party protocol from Cleve's paper.But i wonder if it is possible to achieve fairness in multi-party setting when the number of honest parties is more than the number of dishonest parties?

Yes, if you assume a broadcast channel then fully secure computation (which implies fairness) is possible if you have an honest majority. Goldreich's book describes a protocol for doing this; more efficient solutions are possible.

is the book 'Foundations of cryptography-Basic Application'?
